# Get windows credentials to use as ClientCredentials (System.ServiceModel.ClientCredentials) for CRM

Tags: .net, windows, crm, credentials

I am making a web form that will simplify some CRM account data manipulation.  I want my users to be able to connect to CRM using their windows login without having to type it in.

**Is there a way to get a user's windows credentials with a .NET web application to be used for CRM authentication?**

Right now I am using the following:

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
Credentials.UserName.UserName = "hardcoded username";
Credentials.UserName.Password = "hardcoded password";
```

but I would like to automate this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialsCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Your web application must be configured to Windows Authentication.

Comment: actually, i was using something similar:
    ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();

and while this worked initially, it throws an exception and so i tried to build around that.  seems like authentication failed.  would you know why that would be?  perhaps an iis issue? (it works in debug mode with default creds, but not over localhost)

Comment: Can you put here the full exception.